# Duplicating the nodes and relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.1.2 community edition.

I want to replicate the nodes and relationships to a new path from the existing old path. Consider i have one hierarchy.

Company:Google
Street : 5760 W 96th Street
City:Marco
State : FL
Country : US

For the first time i will create a hierarchy with 4nodes with some relationships. The relationship looks like as below:

```
Create (Google)-[:located_at]->(Marco)-[:belongs_to]->(FL)-[:present_in]->(US)
```

And then I will create one more company node called as Yahoo and this company is having different street name and same city, state and country name as same as Google.

So now i want to create  a yahoo node and street node , and wanted to copy the city, state and country node along with their relationships to this node.So here I wanted to copy the existing nodes into my new path.

How can i do it?

My new node looks like this :

```
Company: Yahoo
Street : 199 Grandview Road
City : Marco
Sate : FL
Country : US
```

I do not want to attach the yahoo node with the Google node's city, state, country nodes.
(These two paths present in a same database )

Comment: i advise you to not create duplicate nodes for cities, states, countries. it will have no sense to use a graph db than

Comment: @Ulkas, yes here in the above example which i have shared does not make any sense but in my real case the requirement is such a way that i have duplicate the path.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an odd way to use a graph database, duplicating the nodes, but if you simply run another `Create` it will create duplicate nodes. The only thing that would prevent you from having all these duplicates is any unique constraints that you may have setup.

```
CREATE(:Company{name:'Google'})-[:located_at]->(:City{name:'Marco'})-[:belongs_to]->(:State{abbrv:'FL'})-[:present_in]->(:Country{name:'United States'})
```

If Marco exists and has properties and you do not want to recreate it from scratch, but create a duplicate then you can:

```
MATCH (marco:City{name:'Marco'}), (fl:State{abbrv:'FL'}), (us:Country{name:'United States'})
CREATE (:Company{name:'Yahoo'})-[:located_at]->(:City{name:marco.name})-[:belongs_to]->(:State{abbrv:fl.abbrv})-[:present_in]->(:Country{name:us.name)
```

If you changed your mind and did want to share a common path, you might use:

```
MATCH (marco:City{name:'Marco'})
CREATE (:Company{name:'Yahoo'})-[:located_at]->(macro)
```

And to prevent lots of duplicates you might change that to:

```
MATCH (m:City { name : 'Marco' })
MERGE (:Company { name:'Yahoo' })-[:located_at]->m
```